# How to list all containers running in a pod, including init containers?

Tags: kubernetes

A solution to retrieve all containers running in a pod is to run `kubectl get pods POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath={.spec.containers[*].name}`, however this command line does not provide the init containers.

Is there a way to cleanly retrieve all containers running in a pod, including init containers?

[edit] as svenwltr noted, on Kubernete 1.6.0 or higher, it is possible to retrieve the init container with `kubectl get pods POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath={.spec.initContainers[*].name}` and all containers can be retrieved with `kubectl get pod POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath="{.spec['containers','initContainers'][*].name}"`. However, this is not a valid workaround for lower versions of Kubernetes where `.spec.initContainers` isn't implemented yet.

Answer (score 13):

The init containers are stored in `spec.initContainers`:

```
kubectl get pods POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath={.spec.initContainers[*].name}
```

You can display both with a bit of [JSONPath magic](https://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/jsonpath/):

```
kubectl get pod POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath="{.spec['containers','initContainers'][*].name}"
```

---

Before Kubernetes 1.6 the init containers were stored in `.metadata.annotations."pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers"`. So it should be possible to get them via:

```
kubectl get pods POD_NAME_HERE -o jsonpath='{metadata.annotations."pod.beta.kubernetes.io/init-containers".[*].name}'
```

Unfortunately I cannot test this, because I don't have a cluster with this version. Also joining containers and init containers into a single command looks a bit harder this way.

Comment: This is the correct answer for Kubernetes 1.6.0 and up, though it won't work for earlier versions of Kubernetes

Comment: I updated the answer, but unfortunately I don't have such a cluster here to test it.

Comment: I have one - I can try later and notify you if it works

Comment: This works great and can be combined with discovery of POD name by label, ie `POD_NAME_HERE=$(kubectl get pod -l "app=MYAPP" --all-namespaces -o jsonpath='{.items[0].metadata.name}')`

Comment: I got nothing, so I use `kubectl describe pod <POD NAME>` to see the conainters.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to do this is to use `kubectl describe pod <POD_NAME_HERE>`. This will print the Init Containers in a separate section from the regular Containers of your pod.

Example:

```
$ kubectl describe pod myapp-pod
Name:       myapp-pod
Namespace:  default
[...]
Init Containers:
  init-myservice:
    Container ID:   docker://87c2601c9f18b4e9d63f995e03d83338e1321e016e76798243257d3e682256c2
    Image:      busybox
    Image ID:       docker-pullable://busybox@sha256:3841678eb5ddd5b62fec74d7f530fe633ee7cf11d4e3827c0b74e2e4c2a2466f
    Port:       <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      until nslookup myservice; do echo waiting for myservice; sleep 2; done;
    State:      Running
      Started:      Thu, 02 Nov 2017 10:54:01 -0400
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-38lv5 (ro)
  init-mydb:
    Container ID:
    Image:      busybox
    Image ID:
    Port:       <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      until nslookup mydb; do echo waiting for mydb; sleep 2; done;
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-38lv5 (ro)
Containers:
  myapp-container:
    Container ID:
    Image:      busybox
    Image ID:
    Port:       <none>
    Command:
      sh
      -c
      echo The app is running! && sleep 3600
    State:      Waiting
      Reason:       PodInitializing
    Ready:      False
    Restart Count:  0
    Requests:
      cpu:      100m
    Environment:    <none>
    Mounts:
      /var/run/secrets/kubernetes.io/serviceaccount from default-token-38lv5 (ro)
[...]
```